# While building an object for rational number

Tags: java

```
public class Rational {
    int num, denom; /*I'm building an object named "Rational, which takes in two int values, num and denom, and represent them as a rational number(num/denom)*/
    public Rational(int a, int b){//this is the constructor
        this.num = a;
        this.denom = b;

    }
public Rational(){//this is just another form of constructor
    this.num = 0;
    this.denum = 0;

}
public static void printRational(Rational x){/*this is the method that prints the rational number in a fractional format*/
 System.out.println(x.num+"/"+x.denom);
}
public static int gcd(int a, int b){/*this is the method which finds the greatest common denominator of numerator of denominator. This will be used to simplify the fraction*/
    if(b == 0){
        return a;
    }
    else{
        return gcd(b, a%b);
    }
}
public static Rational add(Rational x, Rational y){/*this is a method which adds the two rational numbers(or objects) together, then simplify it utilizing the gcd method*/
    Rational z = new Rational();
    z.denom = (x.denom * y.denom);
    z.num = y.num*x.denom + x.num*y.denom;
    z.denom = z.denom/gcd(z.num, z.denom);
    z.num = z.num/gcd(z.num, z.denom);
    return z;

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rational y = new Rational(1, 2); //1st Rational Object: y
        Rational z = new Rational(2, 6); //2nd Rational Object: z
        printRational(add(y, z)); //implementing the method
        //result? so far so good. I get the correct result
    }

}
```

The problem I'm facing is I don't understand is that why this won't work instead and give me an error.

```
public static Rational add(Rational x, Rational y){
    Rational z = new Rational();
    int a = (x.denom * y.denom);
    int b = y.num*x.denom + x.num*y.denom;
    z.denom = a/gcd(z.num, z.denom);
    z.num = b/gcd(z.num, z.denom);
    return z;

}
```

Why would this give me an error message: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at Rational.add(Rational.java:47)
    at Rational.main(Rational.java:58)" when the instances of the object are `int` types and I'm temporarility storing the value into `int a, b;`  Help me please if you see something I don't see!!  Thank you.

Comment: Can u paste the stacktrace ?

Comment: what's a stacktrace?

Comment: I don't believe your code will currently compile.  I am testing it now in IntelliJ.

Comment: @user87902 In computing, a stack trace (also called stack backtrace or stack traceback) is a report of the active stack frames at a certain point in time during the execution of a program.

Comment: sorry there were a couple of syntax errors when I tried to change the misspelling of denominator(from denuminator

Comment: While you are talking about error, you should post the error first!!!!!

Comment: Your code seems to be running fine in my IntelliJ, insofar as adding `1 / 2` and `2 / 6` gives `5 / 6` as the result.  Please post your stack trace, as it may have nothing to do with your math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know what is the exact problem, when you say "It is not working". It would have been helpful if you could tell what error is it giving. However, from what you have said, Could it be because you have not initialized ***z.num*** and ***z.denom*** and are sending them to ***gcd()*** ?? They will both be zero, as they are ***primitive data type "int"*** so your ***gcd method will return 0*** and cause an exception.

```
public static Rational add(Rational x, Rational y){
  Rational z = new Rational();
  int a = (x.denom * y.denom);
  int b = y.num*x.denom + x.num*y.denom;
  z.denom = a/gcd(z.num, z.denom); <--------------
  z.num = b/gcd(z.num, z.denom); <--------------
  return z; 
}
```

Comment: Oh my goodness. That's right. Made a such... puny mistake. LOL. Took a quite a bit of time posting the question. I should've looked into it more carefully

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong implementation for dividing with gcd as the number changes in this case.

```
z.denom = z.denom/gcd(z.num, z.denom);
z.num = z.num/gcd(z.num, z.denom);//z.denom is changed here.
```

The `z.denom` can be `0` as it is changed so gcd is `0` and hence the exception.

So what you can do is.

```
int gcd = gcd(z.num, z.denom);
z.denom /= gcd;
z.num /= gcd;
```

Also this fails when either of num or denom is a `0`.

Comment: yeah. Since I didn't assign any new value to those instances z.denom and z.num, it's using the 0 as default.  Before I posted this question, my program includes this public Rational(){
 this.num = 0;
 this.denum = 0;

}

Comment: as well. That's why it's getting 0/0 and giving me errors I get it. Thank you